# Angular 6 Caracteres especiais (Acentuação e cedilha)

Tags: angular, typescript

Boa noite,
Alguem sabe como resolver o problema com acentuação no Angular 6?

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Minha Primeira Aplicação' ;
}
```

Sai assim:

Bem vindo a Minha Primeira Aplica��o!

***Resolvido:***

Na hora de salvar no Visual Studio tem que especificar que é pra salvar com UTF-8 com e sem assinatura funcionaram. (File > Save as > Save with encoding(no botão save tem um combo))

Answer (score 0):

adicione a tag

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Dentro do head do seu arquivo index.html

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Já estava com a tag Meta com Charset=utf-8, acredito ser algo do Typescript ou do próprio Angular.

Comment: Eu fiz um teste aqui e funcionou, pode ser uma configuração do seu servidor. Você esta usando o angular-cli?

Comment: Sim Angular CLI para criar o projeto, e depois importado para o Visual Studio 2017 para trabalhar, o servidor esta sendo o IIS Express do visual studio

Comment: deve ser uma configuração desse servidor.

Comment: Vou verificar aqui, jogar direto pro IIS, muito obrigado, aviso se funcionar

Comment: Coloquei no IIS, todas as configurações UTF-8 e Português Brasil e nada ainda :(

Comment: Não é servidor, criei um novo com o CLI, alterei o app.component e rodei com ng serve --open e deu o mesmo problema. Mas já descobri o que é, abri o componente com notepad++ e alterei para UTF-8 sem BOM daí funcionou, agora é ver no VS como configurar para salvar assim. Muito obrigado pela boa vontade :)